# After upgrade to Chrome 120 selenium test started to show error "This site can't be reached"

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, https

I see issue after upgrade from chrome 119 to chrome 120 where selenium test started to fail. There is suddenly

```
This site can't be reached
ERR_TIMEOUT
```

displayed instead of expected page. In tomcat log, I can see error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x000x010x000x010xfc0x030x030xff0xd70xc30xff>R0xfe0xc50x970xb40x1c_0x87h]0xa65*0x89e0xcf0x010x08v0xea0xc60xe80xad0xaf0xc4=0xdd ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

which points to the use of HTTPS request while server expects HTTP.

In this test I never use HTTPS, it's http only and I don't ask for HTTPS anywhere.
Also additional information is - there is loadbalancer included in this test, however it is used before the error on different DNS. Maybe there is some relation, however when test breaks, it's already out of the loadbalancer part.

Tests without selenium shows that server and that URL is responding alright. When I switch from Chrome 120 to Firefox, test works alright. Did not try to downgrade Chrome to 119.

Also local run with chrome 120.0.6099.71 don't show error. While jenkins test run uses chrome 120.0.6099.109 and shows error.

Anyone sees something similar?

Any ideas how to solve this or proceed with debugging?

Answer (score 1):

We saw the exact same thing after upgrading Chrome last week. Using the UI, chrome loads the http page fine, but when trying to navigate to http using Selenium API, chrome forces to https. We could not find a solution, so we added an SSL cert to the internal server to allow https.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Selenide in Kotlin and fased the same problem. And yes - currenyly there's no solution to this. Also there's no argument for ChromeOptions() that we can pass to avoid this.

Here's what I've done to avoid this proplem while testing using Chome locally on my PC: I've created a local proxy server, that replaces all https:// to http:// and passed it to WebDriver capabilities. Here's Kotlin example:

First you imclude selenode-proxy and proxy server sulotion:

```
implementation("net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core:2.1.5")
implementation("com.codeborne:selenide-proxy:7.0.4")
```

Then create a proxy server and pass it to Selenide via Configuration.proxy:

```
    //Create and start a new proxy instance
    val proxy = BrowserMobProxyServer()
    proxy.start(0) // 0 if you want a random port

    // change all http t https
    proxy.addRequestFilter { request, contents, messageInfo ->
        if (messageInfo.originalUrl.startsWith("https://")) {
            val httpUrl: String = messageInfo.originalUrl.replaceFirst("https", "http")
            request.setUri(httpUrl)
        }
        null
    }

    Configuration.proxyEnabled = true
}
```